# CakePHP - LiveSearch / AutoSuggest / AutoComplete Search using AJAX/Jquery

Tags: jquery, cakephp, search, autocomplete, autosuggest

I'd been trying to develop one with this for a long time. I'd try a lot of tutorial,but nothing works.

So my simple question, is there anybody know a good tutorial on making an autocomplete/autosuggest search in CAkePHP.

I'm using CakePHP 1.3.

Thanx in advance to all.

Comment: Hi, i will write a tutorial for this tomorrow. Hold tight.

Comment: I started writing one, and then realized that I was basically going to write what is already written here: http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/05/07/jquery-autocomplete-in-cakephp/   good luck

Comment: thanks to all.. I'll try it first..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a suggestion:

- [JqueryUI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)
- [CakePHP JSON-generated output](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/05/07/json-output-with-cakephp/)

This way you communicate with server via jquery ui and output search results as json.
There's a good article at Teknoid's site covering this:
 - [JQuery autocomplete in CakePHP](http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/05/07/jquery-autocomplete-in-cakephp/)

Answer (score 0):

Well you could try this [Live Search](http://www.justkez.com/cakephp-livesearch/)
Though its done in CakePHP 1.2 you could get the concepts of implementation and create your own from it for 1.3 version.
Hope it helps in some way.

Comment: i'd try that one.. that is one of many that I try that is not happening in Cakephp 1.3 .. I dont know if my code is wrong but the main concept I get from there.